# "Spanning" a category

Tags: category-theory

What does it mean for objects to "span" a category? I know what a span is but I'm not exactly sure what the phrase means. Does it just mean the category consists of the specified objects?

An example of this usage:

> Let K be the subcategory of C spanned by finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_(category_theory)) for a definition.

Comment: Can you show an example of such usage in context?

Comment: I know what a span is in some category. I don't know what the following means: Let K be the subcategory of C spanned by finite dimensional vector spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from your comment, you mean "spanning" (somewhat) in the sense of graph theory. More common than "subcategory spanned by the objects with property $A$" is the term "full subcategory of objects with property $A$"; at the very least I think this what is meant here:

This is simply the subcategory that you get by keeping just the objects with property $A$ (in your example $A$ means: "is finite dimensional") and all the morphisms between those objects. Such a subcategory is called "full" because the inclusion functor in the original category is full in this case.