# full subcategory of $Fun(C,D)$ spanned by a collection of functors

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$, $D$ be to categories. Now let $J$ be a collection of functors from $C$ to $D$. Then, what is the full subcategory of $Fun(C,D)$ spanned by J?

Basically, I am trying to understand the definition of a pro-object of a category. In one of Lurie’s notes, he defined the category of pro-objects of $C$, where $C$ is a category which has all finite limits, to be the opposite category of the full subcategory of $Fun(C,Set)$ spanned by functors which they preserve finite limits.

Comment: $J$ forms a subset of the objects of $\mathrm{Fun}(C, D)$. The full subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}(C, D)$ restricted to objects in $J$ is the "subcategory spanned by $J$".

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Spanning" a category](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791963/spanning-a-category)

Comment: @varkor Many thanks for your comments. As you said and as It is mentioned in that post, it is indeed what I think that it should be. But, I asked it here to see if I am wrong.